# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.mail.Address error when running from AIX

Tags: java, jar, classpath, aix

I am trying to run a java program on my AIX server.  I wrote the classpath

```
/usr/java6/bin/javac  -classpath :.:/usr/jdk/commons-net-3.0.1.jar:/usr/jdk/classes12.jar:/usr/jdk/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar:/usr/jdk/jtds-1.2.5.jar:/urs/jdk/mail.jar:/usr/jdk/joda-time-1.6.2.jar:/usr/jdk/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/jdk/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpclient-cache-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpcore-4.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpmime-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/mailapi.jar:/usr/jdk/pop3.jar:/usr/jdk/smtp.jar:/usr/jdk/dsn.jar:/usr/jdk/imap.jar -d . *.java
```

which seems to compile correctly.  Then when I run the program

```
java daily_transmission
```

i get the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.mail.Address.   All the .jar files that were in Eclipse when it worked before are in the /usr/jdk file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`NoClassDefFoundError`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) means that ([quoting the relevant JavaDoc)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html):

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found.
>
> The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing
>   class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

Two things to check:

1. Firstly, you appear to have have a typo in your classpath (though it can't have been there when you compiled the code, or it wouldn't have compiled successfully, so that's clearly not the root cause of the exception you're seeing.):

   ```
   /urs/jdk/mail.jar
   ```

   should be

   ```
   /usr/jdk/mail.jar
   ```
2. Make sure that you are also using the -classpath option to pass the classpath to `java` as well as to `javac` to pick up those `.jar` files at runtime:

   ```
   java -classpath :.:/usr/jdk/commons-net-3.0.1.jar:/usr/jdk/classes12.jar:/usr/jdk/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar:/usr/jdk/jtds-1.2.5.jar:/urs/jdk/mail.jar:/usr/jdk/joda-time-1.6.2.jar:/usr/jdk/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/jdk/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpclient-cache-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpcore-4.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpmime-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/mailapi.jar:/usr/jdk/pop3.jar:/usr/jdk/smtp.jar:/usr/jdk/dsn.jar:/usr/jdk/imap.jar daily_transmission
   ```

Comment: ah, thank you, fixed the typo, however I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you passing the classpath to java as well as to javac? Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError means that the ClassLoader was able to find the class, but it was not able to be loaded. This usually happens when some static field in the offending class could not be initialized. So I am sure that your classpath might be correct; but some static field in that class could not be set correctly.

Comment: NoClassDefFound means that the class definition [couldn't be found](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html).

Comment: When did I say that the class definition could be found? I just said that the .class file is available in the classpath.

Comment: When you said *NoClassDefFoundError means that the ClassLoader was able to find the class*. The JavaDoc contradicts this.

Comment: Yes, the classloader was indeed able to find the class in the classpath. Otherwise a ClassNotFound exception would have been thrown. Finding the class and finding the class definition are two different things.

Comment: Fair enough - then I misinterpreted your answer.